# How to customise Material Design TextField Component error state iOS

Tags: ios, material-design, textfield, mdc-components

Trying to customize the error state floating label `colour` and the inline error message `font/colour` but cannot find any option or in the docs.

[image]

MD Docs: https://material.io/develop/ios/components/textfields/

Comment: Does this question solved? I can't find it too.

Comment: For now, I convinced the designer that he needs to work with this color  but not, didn’t find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **MDCTextInputControllerOutlined** to change the error color of **MDCTextField**.

```
var textField = MDCTextField()
var textInputController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: textField)
textInputController.errorColor = .red
```